# What is GetOrganizationService in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I was looking at code provided at
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978236/pass-a-parameter-to-a-crm-2011-workflow-via-the-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683977/set-and-get-notes-field-in-crm-2011-javascript)

which is supposed to create a Note via javascript. In this code there is a line which reads:

```
var orgService = GetOrganizationService();
```

Do I have to have another function "GetOrganizationService"? If so, can someone show me how to do this?  Or is this a built-in CRM method that will be understood?

Comment: My guess is it's part of Microsoft Dynamics CRM -- see the tags for the question. If you're using some other CRM, it will have a different API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any function like that, my guess is that method is part of a api that someone create to abstract all the work to call for example the Web Services of CRM via Javascript. For example of a api check this [article](http://www.bizforward.cws-international.com/2011/01/26/creating-records-in-crm-2011-using-javascript/) have a example of a annotation.

I know two ways to create a record of entity via Javascript:

Via Web Services of CRM:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc677070.aspx

Via Odata:

- http://lakshmanindian.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/create-noteannotation-using-jscript-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011/